# React Virtualized - How to properly clear the cache of the CellMeasurer

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have an InfiniteLoader wrapping a WindowScroller wrapping a CellMeasurer wrapping a List using react-virtualized. I am seeing inconsistent behavior regarding each list item's height from render to render.

I am trying to pass resetMeasurements to the list rendering component in order to clear the cache on each new render. I just want to make sure I am using it correctly.

Do I just pass the function as a prop to the List rendering component, and then in my render function call resetMeasurements() before returning the List?

Comment: "_I am trying to pass resetMeasurements to the list rendering component in order to clear the cache on each new render. I just want to make sure I am using it correctly._" No. This is not the way it's intended to be used. This would effectively disable caching.

Comment: @brianvaughn I just wanted to see if the inconsistent rendering was related to caching, so this did work for testing purposes. However, the caching appears to not be the issue.